# What's $\sum_{n \ge 0} q^{n^2}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Is there a relatively simple way of calculating the sum of the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{n^2}, \quad |q|<1 ?$$

Comment: It is related to the [Jacobi theta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) $\vartheta_3(z,q)$.  May I ask, what is the motivation for your question?

Comment: It's to do with deriving the partition function for a photon in a box, where the sums can't be approximated very well by integrals.

Comment: So are you interested in how to evaluate it numerically?  Or is there some analytical aspect you need?

Comment: Yes, numerical methods would be sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is can be written in terms of the [Jacobi theta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html), $$\vartheta_{3}(q)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}q^{n^{2}}.$$  Specifically, your function is $\frac{1}{2}\left(\vartheta_{3}(q)+1\right).$  I am not sure what you mean by calculating the series for $q<1$, but there are several known special values, for example $\theta_3\left(e^{-\pi}\right)=\pi^{1/4}\Gamma\left(3/4\right)^{-1},$ and it satisfies the functional equation $$\vartheta_{3}\left(e^{-\pi x}\right)\vartheta_3\left(e^{-\pi/x}\right)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}. $$

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_theta_function for more information.

Comment: That functional equation also means that it's relatively easy to compute to high accuracy for almost all values, since one of $e^{-\pi x}$ or $e^{-\pi/x}$ will generally be so small as to let the defining sum converge very, very rapidly.  (Also, IIRC the functional equation is one of the classical applications of Poisson summation, but that's more tangential.)